CMake Dependency Management With FetchContent and ExternalProject
I have a C++ project using CMake as a build system, and I'd like to use cucumber-cpp. In this project, I have a GTest/ GMock dependency which I resolve as per the instructions here (mixture of FetchContent_Declare and FetchContent_MakeAvailable).
I then try to add the cucumber-cpp dependency with the following:
ExternalProject_Add(
  CucumberCpp
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp.git"
  GIT_TAG v0.7
  CMAKE_ARGS 
    -DCUKE_ENABLE_GTEST=ON -DCUKE_TESTS_UNIT=OFF 
    -DCUKE_ENABLE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DCUKE_ENABLE_BOOST_TEST=OFF -DCUKE_ENABLE_QT=OFF 
    -DCUKE_TESTS_VALGRIND=OFF)

However, I can see CMake complain that GTest can't be found when configuring cucumber-cpp:
[1/9] Creating directories for 'googletest-populate'
[1/9] Performing download step (git clone) for 'googletest-populate'
Cloning into 'googletest-src'...
HEAD is now at f8d7d77c Bump version to v1.14 in preparation for release
[2/9] Performing disconnected update step for 'googletest-populate'
[3/9] No patch_disconnected step for 'googletest-populate'
[5/9] No configure step for 'googletest-populate'
[6/9] No build step for 'googletest-populate'
[7/9] No install step for 'googletest-populate'
[8/9] No test step for 'googletest-populate'
[9/9] Completed 'googletest-populate'
...
[6/16] Performing configure step for 'CucumberCpp'
...
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "1.11.0")

When I go on to build my source using cucumber-cpp, I get various linker failures about being unable to find references to GTestStep. From looking at the cucumber-cpp CMakeLists.txt, it seems the following is problematic:
if(TARGET GTest::gtest)
    list(APPEND CUKE_EXTRA_PRIVATE_LIBRARIES GTest::gtest)
    list(APPEND CUKE_SOURCES drivers/GTestDriver.cpp)
endif()

I appear to be able to resolve this issue if I just apt install libgtest-dev libgmock-dev then rebuild, but I want to continue building GTest/ GMock from source in my project. Unsure whether I'm doing something silly here.

It's been a long time since I was involved with Cucumber-CPP or Cucumber, and I haven't written any C++ code since, so these are mainly observations.

What I can see is that CUKE_ENABLE_GTEST drives the required inclusion of GoogleTest library in CMake: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/blob/f468ce65f68e1560d22b4bc14e5e489b2651776e/CMakeLists.txt#L146C5-L146C17
The actual compilation relies on the GTest::gtest target and not on CUKE_ENABLE_GTEST: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/blob/f468ce65f68e1560d22b4bc14e5e489b2651776e/src/CMakeLists.txt#L25

I imagine that you are not compiling GTest from sources separately, or you should be able to define GTEST_ROOT (I believe) ...as that's how I used to build it in the past. I believe that you are instead building GTest in the same CMake project. Perhaps you can explore this...

Import Cucumber-CPP with -DCUKE_ENABLE_GTEST=OFF (so that it won't try to import the required library via CMake)
If the GTest sources that you are building provide the GTest::gtest target, the GTestDriver will be compiled and the GTest library linked.

Good luck!
